# topnav place form item divs in the correct order

Tags: html, css, navbar

**Background**

I am trying to make a template for a git repo web viewer so it better matches with the rest of my website. I am starting with the top navigation bar. I have been able to put the items I want: logo, menu item links, select menu for branch, and search box.

**Problem**

I placed the div container for the select menu first and the div container for the search box second. Yet, the two appear in reverse order. I want them back in the correct order as I placed them in the code.

**Code**

Note: for best results, use a wide window. I will work on responsiveness once this is working.

```css
/*
 *  Add a black background color to the top navigation
 */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #444;
}

    /*
     *  Make a style for fixing the menu to the top.
     */
    .fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/*
 *  Style the links inside the navigation bar
 */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

/*
 *  Add an active class to highlight the current page
 */
.active {
    background-color: #6666;
    color: #eee;
}

/*
 *  Style image in topnav.
 */
.logo {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}


/*
 *  Style image in topnav.
 */
.topnav-image a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

/*
 *  Right-aligned section inside the top navigation
 */
.topnav-right {
    float: right;
}

/*
 *  Style the right aligned links inside the navigation bar
 */
.topnav-right a {
    font-size: 16pt;
}

/*
 *  Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on
 *  small screens
 */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

/*
 *  Change the color of links on hover
 */
/*
 *  Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover
 */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
}

.topnav .branch-container {
    float: right;
}

.topnav .branch-container select {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 4px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: #eeeeee;
    background-color: #666666;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
}

.topnav .search-container {
    float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 16pt;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #666666;
    color: #eeeeee;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
    /*float: right;*/
    /*padding: 10px 10px;*/
    display: none;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #444;
    color: #eee;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
    background: #666;
    color: #eee;
}

::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: #eee;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: #eee;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: #eee;
}

/*
 *  Format the footer.
 */
.footer {
 position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: black;
}

/*
 *  Style the links inside the footer.
 */
.footer a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

/*
 *  Right-aligned section inside the footer.
 */
.footer-right {
    float: right;
}

/*
 *  Hover effect of footer items.
 */
.footer a:hover {
 background-color: #dddddd;
 color: black;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/*
 *  Format the main content.
 */
.main {
    /*padding: 16px;*/
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

h1.title {
 font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Repos: Ali Kakakhel</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fixed">
        <nav class="topnav" id="mytopnav">
            <div class="topnav-image">
                <a href="https://git.kakakhel.io"><img src="https://git-scm.com/images/logos/downloads/Git-Icon-1788C.png" class="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <a href="https://git.kakakhel.io/RepoName/SummaryPage">RepoName</a>
            <div class="topnav-right">
                <a href="https://git.kakakhel.io/RepoName/AboutPage">About</a>
                <a href="https://git.kakakhel.io/RepoName/SummaryPage" class="active">Summary</a>
                <a href="https://git.kakakhel.io/RepoName/RefsPage">Refs</a>
                <a href="https://git.kakakhel.io/RepoName/LogPage">Log</a>
                <a href="https://git.kakakhel.io/RepoName/TreePage">Tree</a>
                <a href="https://git.kakakhel.io/RepoName/CommitPage">Commit</a>
                <a href="https://git.kakakhel.io/RepoName/DiffPage">Diff</a>
                <a href="https://git.kakakhel.io/RepoName/StatsPage">Stats</a>
                <div class="branch-container">
                    <select>
                        <option value="Master">Master</option>
                        <option value="Branch1">Branch1</option>
                        <option value="Branch2">Branch2</option>
                        <option value="Branch3">Branch3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="search-container">
                    <form action="/action_page.php">
                        <input type="text" id="SearchInput" placeholder="Search...">
                        <button type="submit" id="SearchButton" onclick="javascript:alert('Hello World!')"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <p>
            Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries
            Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they
            live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large
            language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and
            supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic
            country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer" id="myfooter">
  <a>Description</a>
  <div class="footer-right">
   <a>Owner</a>
  </div>
 </div>
    <script>
    var input = document.getElementById("SearchInput");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById("SearchButton").click();
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: they are both float right, so you have to have them in reverse order in your html. thats just how float right works

Comment: Playing around, I noticed that I had to give both containers `float: right;` so that they would be on one row. Otherwise they end up on their own rows. Is there a simpler method I have not learned yet?